# How to add a unique ID to each entry in my JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have this array of JSON objects:

[image: JSON]

and I want to add a unique ID (string) to each entry, like this:

```
let myTree = [
    {
        text: 'Batteries',
        id: '0',
        children: [
            {
                text: 'BatteryCharge',
                id: '0-0'
            },
            {
                text: 'LiIonBattery',
                id: '0-1'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'Supplemental',
        id: '1',
        children: [
            {
                text: 'LidarSensor',
                id: '1-0',
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Side',
                        id: '1-0-0'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Tower',
                        id: '1-0-1'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I just can't think of the right logic to achieve this. I have written this recursive function, which obviously does not achieve what I want:

```
function addUniqueID(tree, id=0) {
    if(typeof(tree) == "object"){
        // if the object is not an array
        if(tree.length == undefined){
            tree['id'] = String(id);
        }
        for(let key in tree) {
            addUniqueID(tree[key], id++);
        }
    }
}
addUniqueID(myTree);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd recommend trying out a package like UUID. But, if this data is going into a database like Mongo or SQL, they will be automatically ID'd and you gotta follow their ID system rules.

Comment: So, the JSON objects are essentially directory trees. The data is not going into a database. I need to add the IDs to each JSON object according to the format I described, because those IDs are then parsed to get the path to each subdirectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a number/id in the recursive function I build a string.

```js
let myTree = [{
    text: 'Batteries',
    children: [{
        text: 'BatteryCharge'
      },
      {
        text: 'LiIonBattery'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'Supplemental',
    children: [{
      text: 'LidarSensor',
      children: [{
          text: 'Side'
        },
        {
          text: 'Tower'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];


function addUniqueID(arr, idstr = '') {
  arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
    obj.id = `${idstr}${i}`;
    if (obj.children) {
      addUniqueID(obj.children, `${obj.id}-`);
    }
  });
}

addUniqueID(myTree);

console.log(myTree);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.

why don't you consider using uuid?

In node there is the uuid module which you can use to generate unique identifiers, I share a base example:

install:

```
npm install uuid
npm i --save-dev @types/uuid
```

code:

```
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';

let _id = uuid();
```